# How to know on app store if an app is universal or has 2 binaries

Tags: iphone, ios4, app-store, universal

Can I tell if an app that is featured on both iPad store and iPhone store are 2 different binaries or just one universal app ?

Can I assume that if it has the "+" it's universal and if it's not it's 2 different binaries ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the '+' sign indicate that a app is universal if a + sign is not there and you see the app on iphone it will be iPhone only or if you see the app on iPad store it will be iPad only.

source : http://www.tipb.com/2010/07/05/equals-universal-iphoneipad-app-app-store/